Given a symmetric diagonally dominant matrix, does $-|a_{ii}|\le \sum_{j\neq i} a_{ij}$ hold?
I am studying linear algebra and I am playing with some basic notion (symmetric matrices, pivots, diagonal matrices etc).
Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix and consider the property:
$$(1) \qquad |a_{ii}|\ge \sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|\quad\text{ for all } i,$$
which is related to the definition in here:
Diagonally dominant matrix
Also, consider the property
$$(2)\qquad -|a_{ii}|\le \sum_{j\neq i} a_{ij} \quad\text{ for all } i.$$
I am wondering if there is any relation between the two properties, i.e. $(1)\implies (2)$ or $(2)\implies (1)$.
The only thing that I can say so far is that if $(2)$ holds, then
$$-|a_{ii}| \le \sum_{j\neq i} a_{ij} \le \sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}|$$
but it does not give $(1)$.
Anyone could help me in understanding if there is any relation between $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix such that … what?

@LSpice just a symmetric matrix.

We have that $(1)$ implies $(2)$ as multiplying the first inequality yields $$-\vert a_{ii}\vert \leq \sum_{j\neq i} (-\vert a_{ij}\vert).$$ Using $$-\vert a_{ij}\vert \leq a_{ij}$$ we get the second inequality. The second inequality does not imply the first one. Consider a matrix with zeros on the diagonal and such that $$\sum_{j\neq i} a_{ij}=0.$$

@SeverinSchraven thanks a lot!
